# Solution of $x^3y'''+6x^2y''+7xy'+y=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I used the Euler-Cauchy method by assuming $y=x^m$ to get the following characteristics equation 
$$(m+1)^3=0$$
that means 
$m1=m2=m3=-1$

Now I want only to know the form of solution

thanks

Comment: Perhaps you mean $+y$, not $+1$?

Comment: yes ,thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Multiple roots of the characteristic equation produce logarithmic factors, so 
in addition to $x^{-1}$ you have $x^{-1} \ln(x)$ and $x^{-1} (\ln(x))^2$ as solutions.

Answer (score 0):

This is a Cauchy-Euler ODE.

Assume that the solution to our ODE takes on the form $y=x^m$

Substituting this into our homogeneous ODE, gives:
$$x^3m(m-1)(m-2)x^{m-3} + 6x^2m(m-1)x^{m-2}+7xmx^{m-1}+x^m = 0$$
Which, quite easily, simplifies to 
$$(m+1)^3=0$$

This characteristic equation gives us three equal roots, namely
$$m_1=m_2=m_3=-1$$

Our general solution to our ODE is thus given by
$$y= c_1x^{-1} + c_2x^{-1}\ln(x) + c_3x^{-1}\ln^2{(x)}$$ where $c_1, c_2, c_3 \in \mathbb{R}$